# How to check if table include more than 1 the same attribute?

Tags: javascript, include

atm I'm learning JS/Angular and making project using these technologies and I need some help here.

```
table = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];

if(table.includes('a' > 2))  #its not working, idk how to make it
{
   console.log("We have 2 the same atributes in our table");
}
```

How to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array and check it's length

```
if(table.filter(item => item === 'a').length > 1) {

}
```